# How to know the host IP by running the docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` file. Through my `docker-compose`, I'm running multiple services. For each service, I'm running the different containers. Among these containers, I have one container which is responsible to get the hardware and network info of the host machine. When I'm running the container in a standalone mode the container is able to provide me with the host IP. But unfortunately, when I'm running it along with other containers (most precisely through the `docker-compose` file), then I'm not able to get the host network information, rather than I'm always getting the bridge network information (i.e., the `docker-compose` internal network information). I tried to set the `network_mode:host` in my service, but unfortunately, when I set it, stops communicating with the other containers. Can anyone please suggest me the way of getting the host network information without tampering the internal communication between different service containers.

Comment: Hello! So if I understand correctly, you can't discover you host info if you run it with the default service bridge, you can if you run it in network_mode:host but then you lose connection to your other services? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes....you're right

Answer (score 0):

You could, perhaps, have this container in two networks. One with the host information, and the other for the 'internal' communication with the containers.

For example:
https://success.docker.com/article/multiple-docker-networks

Answer (score 0):

Without a dockerfile and a docker-compose it's hard to test but I think that if you have a container with network_mode:host, you have to access other container trough the host only, that mean port forwarding, so if you have your container in host mode, and another binded to localhost 8080, I think you should be able to ping localhost:8080 from the host mode container.

Give me feedback about this, please!

Have fun!

Comment: You can find the `docker-compose` file in the following link: `(https://github.com/mF2C/mF2C/blob/master/docker-compose-it2/docker-compose.yml)`. Where you will find one service named - `resource-categorization` . The idea is that this `resource-categorization` service will capture and provide the host IP along with its other output parameters. So, can you please tell me what I have to do?